# Adding text to existing item of QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.5

So I wanted to add an additional text to my `QListWidget` list with code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->history->count(); i++ )
{
    ui->history->item(i)->text().append(QTime::currentTime().toString());
}
```

This does not worked.

I've *`qDebug`ged* all list items with this code:

```
qDebug() << "item(" << i << ")->text() : " << ui->history->item(i)->text();
```

After that i received this output:

```
item( 0 )->text() :  "http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cT6wV9PDKI-8zAXjlaCIDw"
item( 1 )->text() :  "https://news.google.ru/nwshp?hl=ru&tab=wn"  
item( 2 )->text() :  "https://news.google.ru/news?pz=1&hl=ru&tab=nn"
item( 3 )->text() :  "https://news.google.ru/news?pz=1&hl=ru&tab=nn"
```

Obviously this function outputs all text of item, so why cannot I append any other string there?

Comment: Maybe you must use `addItem("something")` before making `append` :-? ( in case you didn't use it already )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit sharing ensures the text is not directly changed. You have to explicitly set the text value:

```
QString txt = ui->history->item(i)->text().append(QTime::currentTime().toString());
ui->history->item(i)->setText (txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

`text()` returns the text by value, not by reference. You need to use `setText` to modify the text.